# What QGIS line styles work best with Garmin maps?

Tags: qgis, garmin

I am using QGIS to create some maps to load on to a GPS using the plugin.  When I display the maps on the GPS the lines are very faint and I can not distinguish colours and some colours vanish altogether. But even the black lines don't stand out.

I have tried increasing the thickness of the lines in QGIS but this does not seem to make any difference.

I am displaying the maps on an ETrex 30.

Comment: Do you want to upload a vector (GPX or gmapsupp.img) or raster (kmz) file?

Comment: I was using the plugin to generate a kmz file but I am open to using alternative methods.  I would prefer a vector based solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Garmin ETREX 30 is announced to have 65000 colours, meaning that it uses [16bit colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_color).

This is quite outdated for modern graphics on computers. So you have to restrict the colours inside QGIS to a 16-bit palette. [8-bit_color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color) or 256 colours would be on the safe side.

Using vector data by exporting GPX files is much easier, but restricted to 200 tracks. Make sure to use `FORCE_GPX_TRACK = Yes` in the layer options on exporting. Styling can be done inside the unit.

Using Garmins own vector format would be best for your purpose. It is possible to create Garmin vector maps from Openstreetmap raw data, and add SRTM contour lines to it. But there is no easy way to create OSM raw data out of QGIS. The OGR driver is read-only. One way would be to export shapefiles to GPX, and do the conversion to osm raw format with the JOSM editor. But keep in mind **NOT** to upload the data on closing the application.

It would be a nice idea for a plugin, if you know how to do it.